# angular 2 error: Can't resolve all parameters for FormGroup

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I am following Thoughtram's tutorial for FormBuilder  http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html  I copied the code and changed a few variable names.  I'm using Angular 2.1.2, Typescript 2.0.8, and Angular Material2 (from Google).  Atom Typescript says no error on any page.  Nonetheless, I get errors at load, and the page does not load with this new code.

```
zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Can't resolve all parameters for FormGroup: (?, ?, ?). ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for FormGroup: (?, ?, ?).(…) Error: Can't resolve all parameters for FormGroup: (?, ?, ?).
at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14598:21)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14499:28)
at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14642:43)
at Array.forEach (native)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14622:21)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14262:36)
at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14367:51)
at Array.forEach (native)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14361:51)
at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17063:49)consoleError @ zone.js:388_loop_1 @ zone.js:417drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:421ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:339
2016-11-10 16:01:40.394 zone.js:390 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't resolve all parameters for FormGroup: (?, ?, ?).(…)consoleError @ zone.js:390_loop_1 @ zone.js:417drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:421ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:339
```

**HTML sample** for apartment4Rent.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="registerApartment4RentForm" (submit)="onSubmit($event)">
  <md-input id="country" name="country" class="required" aria-labelledby="country" formControlName="country"
i18n-placeholder="select country placeholder" placeholder="Country" type="text"  size="30" maxlength="30">
  </md-input>
```

plus 4 more identically for state, city, street, and ZIPcode

**AppComponent** with constructor from the tutorial - in the app folder

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'residence-app',
    templateUrl: "components/navigation/headerFooter.html",
    styleUrls: [ "components/navigation/styleHeaderFooter.css" ],
    providers: [
      FormBuilder,
      FormGroup
    ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    registerApartment4RentForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
    ngOnInit() {
      this.registerApartment4RentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        country: '',
        stateProvince: '',
        address: this.formBuilder.group({
          streetAddress: '',
          zipCode: '',
          city: ''
        })
      });
    }
}
```

The headerFooter.html in the templateUrl has some html for a header and a footer and

```
            <div>
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
```

in between where apartment4Rent.component.html loads and appears before I tried this reactive form code.  My directory structure is app/components/input/apartment4Rent.component(s)

What has to change to make reactive forms work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you add the Angular reactive forms module as an import to your module? It looks like it's missing the services that are registered by that module.

(am on my phone, so sorry for the brief answer)

**Edit**

This is what I mean:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@anglar/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Note the import of ReactiveFormsModule

Comment: thanks. I added import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; to the app.component, but get the same errors.  I edited the code above to show that import

Comment: No, you need to add the import to your ngModule declaration,usually called AppModule, see (http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: I took import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; out of app.component (I can't edit the above code because SO has frozen me), and I put it in app.module.ts   I get very similar errors - mostly the same in a different order.

Comment: I also put ReactiveFormsModule in the imports section, like yours.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have the providers in the components metadata. I don't ever add the and it's also not in the thoughtram post.

Comment: I removed the providers and the page loads. Thanks. The new problem is that none of the md-inputs appear. Checkboxes, etc. do appear.  I suspect some html or MD problem and I'll work that separately.  Thanks, you're good.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. I know how frustrating it can be if something like this eludes you...

Comment: The tutorial has all the code in AppComponent. I have a separate component managing the html input. Here's a summary of changes from the above code. FormBuilder, FormGroup and ReactiveFormsModule come out of App. The providers are deleted. ReactiveFormsModule goes into AppModule in Robba's code. The other 2 go into the component managing input html. The code inside the export class (above) goes into the component managing input html. The implement onInit is not necessary. I think that's all. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

One more reason for this error is when you imported formgroup twice. I removed it in my app module, now it works for me, Hope it help someone.