# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for FormGroup: (?, ?, ?)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm Trying to use de FormBuilder on my Ionic 4 App but it Throws me this error

```
compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for FormGroup: (?, ?, ?).
at syntaxError (compiler.js:2430)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:18983)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:18876)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableTypeMetadata (compiler.js:19098)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:19107)
at compiler.js:19045
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:19005)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:18724)
at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:26025)
```

I've read this question [angular 2 error: Can't resolve all parameters for FormGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537628/angular-2-error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-formgroup) but import the `ReactiveFormsModule` into the appmodule.ts dont solved. Look:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy, ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage'

import { AutenticacaoService } from './services/autenticacao.service'
import { GuardaautenticacaoService } from './services/guardaautenticacao.service'
import { LoadHomeService } from './private/home/load-home.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { TarefasDetalhePageModule } from './private/sharedmodule/tarefas-detalhe/tarefas-detalhe.module'
import { TarefadetalheService } from './private/sharedmodule/tarefas-detalhe/tarefadetalhe.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,
     IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),HttpClientModule,  TarefasDetalhePageModule   ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    AutenticacaoService,
    GuardaautenticacaoService,
    LoadHomeService,
    ModalController,
    TarefadetalheService,
    FormBuilder,
    FormGroup,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

That's my class that is trying to create the form:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams, ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { TarefadetalheService } from './tarefadetalhe.service';
import { Tarefa } from '../../models/tarefa.model';
import { TipoTarefa } from '../../models/tipotarefa.model';

import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tarefas-detalhe',
  templateUrl: './tarefas-detalhe.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tarefas-detalhe.page.scss'],
})
export class TarefasDetalhePage implements OnInit {
 idTarefa = null
 tarefa: Tarefa
 tiposTarefas : TipoTarefa[]
 formulario: FormGroup
  constructor(
    private navParams: NavParams,
    private getTarefaDetalhe: TarefadetalheService,
    private modalController:ModalController,
    public fb: FormBuilder) {   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getGeral()
    this.getTiposTarefas()
    this.createForm()
  }

  getGeral(){
    this.idTarefa = this.navParams.get('id_tarefa');
    this.getTarefaDetalhe.recuperaDetalhes().subscribe((data)=>{ //passar o id da tarefa como parametro no recupera detalhes
    this.tarefa = data
   })
  }
  getTiposTarefas(){
    this.getTarefaDetalhe.recuperaTiposTarefas().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.tiposTarefas = data
    })
  }

  createForm(){
    this.formulario = this.fb.group({
      'tipotarefa':['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
   });
  }
 closeModal()
 {
   this.modalController.dismiss();
 }
}
```

and here's my HTML:

```
<ion-content padding *ngIf="tarefa != null">
  <form [formGroup]="formulario">
    <h4>
      <ion-icon name="list-box"></ion-icon> Geral
    </h4>
    <ion-grid>

      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="8">
          <ion-label position="floating">Tipo de Tarefa</ion-label>
          <ion-select formControlName="tipotarefa" [ngModel]="tarefa.tipoTarefa.id" okText="Confirmar" cancelText="Cancelar">

            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let tipo of tiposTarefas" [value]="tipo.id">{{tipo.descricao}}</ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    <h4>
      <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon> Horário
    </h4>
    <ion-item-divider></ion-item-divider>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="5">
          <ion-label position="stacked">Data</ion-label>
          <ion-datetime display-format="DD-MM-YYYY" max="2050-10-31" picker-format="DD-MM-YYYY" [ngModel]="tarefa.data_tarefa"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="3">
          <ion-label position="stacked">Inicio</ion-label>
          <ion-datetime display-format="HH:mm" picker-format="HH:mm" [ngModel]="tarefa.inicio"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="3">
          <ion-label position="stacked">Fim</ion-label>
          <ion-datetime display-format="HH:mm" picker-format="HH:mm" [ngModel]="tarefa.fim"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    <h4>
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon> Cliente
    </h4>
    <ion-item-divider></ion-item-divider>
    <ion-grid>

      <ion-row>

      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Here's my github repo if you want:
https://github.com/tiagosilveiraa/PManager

Comment: Remove all the unnecessary providers you tried to add getting this to work. Add just the `ReactiveFormsModule` to your imports. Do not add modules to the providers array.

Comment: Now It says that: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

Answer (score 2):

I've Solved it just importing the `ReactiveFormsModule` into the tarefa-detalhe.module.

Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 1):

you need to import `FormsModule` and `ReactiveForms`

Answer (score 0):

You've imported ReactiveFormsModule but not added it to the "imports" for your module. Needs to be added to this list

`imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,
     IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),HttpClientModule,  TarefasDetalhePageModule   ]`

Comment: Now It's throwing this error: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. I removed the ReactiveFormsModule from the providers and put it into the imports from the app module.