# ERROR in Can't resolve all parameters for FormControl in my-project/node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts: (?, ?, ?)

Tags: angular, angular8, form-control

I getting this error just when trying to `build --prod`.

> ERROR in Can't resolve all parameters for FormControl in
>   my-project/node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts: (?, ?, ?).

Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.0",
   }
```

Comment: Did you add `ReactiveFormsModule` to the nearest module?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular 2 error: Can't resolve all parameters for FormGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537628/angular-2-error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-formgroup)

Comment: @hoang Yes, I did.